# Can't stop socket server thread from within

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, connection, python-multithreading

I have the following situation:
I have a class called Server, which is, as the name tells, the class which starts the server and is supposed to stop it. Here's the code:

```
import socket
import threading


class Server:
    def __init__(self, server_manager, host, port, running):
        # Define the host and port to listen on
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.server_manager = server_manager

        # setting stop event up
        self.running = running

        # Create a socket object
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # Bind the socket to the host and port
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))

        # Start listening for up to 5 incoming connections
        self.backlog = 5
        self.server.listen(self.backlog)

    def run(self):
        while not self.running.is_set():
            try:
                # Accept a connection from a client
                client_socket, client_address = self.server.accept()

                client_handler = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
                client_handler.start()
            except socket.error:
                pass

    def handle_client(self, client_socket):
        while not self.running.is_set():
            try:
                client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)  # Receive data from the client
                if not client_data:
                    break

                # Process the received data here

                self.server_manager.show_data(client_data)

                # Send a response back to the client (optional)
                response = "Successfully sent data! Now responding!"
                client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
            finally:
                client_socket.close()

        client_socket.close()

    def close(self):
        # close
        pass
```

I also have a class called ServerManager, which processes the data coming from the server. Again the code:

```
import threading
from ConnectionProcessor.connection import Server


class ServerManager:
    def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", port=6969):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.running = threading.Event()

        self.server = Server(server_manager=self, host=self.host, port=self.port, running=self.running)
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.run)
        self.server_thread.start()

    def close(self):
        self.running.set()

    def show_data(self, data: str):
        print(data)
```

It works well, I can print the data coming from the server. My only problem is, that I can't close the server from my main class:

```
from ConnectionProcessor import ServerManager
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_manager = ServerManager()
    sleep(4)
    server_manager.close()
```

The server is still up and running.

I tried multiple things, also I tried changing self.running from threading.Event to a simple bool, but it has the same effect, it doesn't work.

This is my first time working with threads and socket, maybe it's just a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is related to the way you are handling the self.running event in your Server class. The run method in the Server class has a while loop that continues as long as self.running is not set. However, it seems that the self.running event is not being set properly when you call the close method.

Let's make a few modifications to ensure that the self.running event is set when you call the close method

1. Update the close method in the ServerManager class to also close the
   server:

   class ServerManager:
   # ... (other methods)

   ```
   def close(self):
       self.running.set()  # Set the running event
       self.server.close()  # Close the server
   ```
2. Update the close method in the Server class to close the server
   socket:

   class Server:
   # ... (other methods)

   ```
   def close(self):
       self.running.set()  # Set the running event
       self.server.close()  # Close the server socket
   ```
3. Modify the while loop in the run method in the Server class to check
   both the running event and the server socket status:

   class Server:
   # ... (other methods)

   ```
   def run(self):
       while not self.running.is_set():
           try:
               # Accept a connection from a client
               client_socket, client_address = self.server.accept()

               client_handler = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
               client_handler.start()
           except socket.error:
               if self.running.is_set():
                   break  # Break the loop if running is set
               else:
                   continue  # Continue the loop if it's a different socket error

   # ... (other methods)
   ```

These changes ensure that both the Server and ServerManager classes set the self.running event when the close method is called, and that the while loop in the run method of the Server class checks both the running event and the server socket status.

Now, when you call server_manager.close(), it should properly set the event and close the server, allowing the server to stop gracefully.

Comment: Now I'm getting a weird error that says: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
It's printed out in this part of handle_client():

...except Exception as e:
self.logger.error(f"Error: {e}")
...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `socket.accept` doesn't return until a client connects, so the while loop condition won't check the `running` event without a client connecting.  Set a timeout on the server socket so `accept` periodically returns:

```
    def run(self):
        while not self.running.is_set():
            try:
                # Accept a connection from a client
                self.server.settimeout(1)
                client_socket, client_address = self.server.accept()
            except TimeoutError as e:
                continue
            client_handler = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
            client_handler.start()
```

Another option is to use `select.select` with a timeout to see if there is a waiting connection on the server:

```
import select

...

    def run(self):
        while not self.running.is_set():
            readable, _, _ = select.select([self.server], [], [], 1.0)
            if readable:
                client_socket, client_address = self.server.accept()
                client_handler = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
                client_handler.start()
```